# Detect Chrome debugger

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to create a script which will run when the Chrome debugger is attached (`chrome.debugger.attach`). My understanding is that the debugger is separate from the DevTools, so the DevTools status could be close even when the Chrome debugger is attached.

Is there a way for a client to detect if the [Chrome debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/debugger) is attached to the current tab? AFAIK there's the property `chrome.debugger.attached`, but I believe a client can't read the value; only extensions can read it.

Comment: It's unclear what your question is

Comment: @Sean Basically I'm trying to figure out if there's a way for a client to detect if the [Chrome debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/debugger) is attached to the current tab. AFAIK there's the property `chrome.debugger.attached`, but I believe a client can't read the value; only extensions can read it.

Comment: you can write an extension that calls a function in your main window when that happens

Comment: @DanielA.White Indeed, but I'm trying to do it without writing an extension to detect the debugger.

Comment: There's no way to detect it unless the caller injects some detectable code/DOM. If the caller doesn't attach to iframes you can create a dummy iframe and measure the difference in time to run the same code inside the iframe and in the main page.